# TensorFlowLite tensor with type UINT8 and a Java object of type [[F (which is compatible with the TensorFlowLite type FLOAT32)

Tags: flutter, tensorflow, dart, tensorflow-lite

I was creating a mobile app that can recognize images using flutter and I got this runtime error when testing the app.

```
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Cannot convert between a TensorFlowLite tensor with type UINT8 and a Java object of type [[F (which is compatible with the TensorFlowLite type FLOAT32).
```

I train my custom model using TensorFlow lite Image classification and run it on Google Colab

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After reading some documents. The TensorFlow Lite Model should have a Post-Training quantization. [See here at Image Classification with TensorFlow Lite](https://www.tensorflow.org/lite/tutorials/model_maker_image_classification#:%7E:text=Customize%20Post%2Dtraining%20quantization%20on%20the%20TensorFLow%20Lite%20model)

Run this command to define the quantization configuration.

`config = QuantizationConfig.for_float16()`

Then export the TensorFlow Lite Model with the configuration.

`model.export(export_dir='.', tflite_filename='model_fp16.tflite', quantization_config=config)`

Export the TensorFlow Lite Model Label with the configuration

```
model.export(export_dir='.', quantization_config=config,export_format=ExportFormat.LABEL)
```

Answer (score 0):

inside your code change the output from float to byte
and finally get the float value from byte data.

before:

```
float[][] labelProb = new float[1][labels.size()];
 for (int i = 0; i < labels.size(); ++i) {
      float confidence = labelProb[0][i];
  }
```

after:

```
byte[][] labelProb = new byte[1][labels.size()];
 for (int i = 0; i < labels.size(); ++i) {
      float confidence = (float)labelProb[0][i];
  }
```