# A problem occurred evaluating project ':tflite'

Tags: java, android, flutter, gradle, tflite

I try to use tflite package to create a live object detection app, but it seems that after i installed both the packages :  ***tflite*** and ***camera***, and also writing the detection code it doesn't seem to run .

Packages :
Tflite : https://pub.dev/packages/tflite
Camera : https://pub.dev/packages/camera

this error occure :

`A problem occurred evaluating project ':tflite'.`

The entire Error :

```
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* Where:
Build file 'C:\Users\Hepha\Documents\flutter_windows_2.10.3-stable\flutter\.pub-cache\hosted\pub.dartlang.org\tflite-1.1.2\android\build.gradle' line: 24

* What went wrong:
A problem occurred evaluating project ':tflite'.
> No signature of method: build_a7q9josm4oau2t0m3mow48bac.android() is applicable for argument types: (build_a7q9josm4oau2t0m3mow48bac$_run_closure2) values: [build_a7q9josm4oau2t0m3mow48bac$_run_closure2@c7c7456]   

* Try:
> Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace.
> Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
> Run with --scan to get full insights.

* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 1m 43s
Running Gradle task 'assembleDebug'... 104,7s|Exception: Gradle task assembleDebug failed with exit code 1
```

My *pubspec.yaml* file :

```yaml
dependencies:
  flutter:
    sdk: flutter

  cupertino_icons: ^1.0.2
  camera: ^0.9.4+1
  image_picker: ^0.8.4+11
  tflite: ^1.1.2

dev_dependencies:
  flutter_test:
    sdk: flutter

  flutter_lints: ^2.0.0

flutter:

  uses-material-design: true

  assets:
      - assets/
      - assets/labels.txt
      - assets/metadata_V2.tflite
```

My *android/app/build.gradle* file :

```dart
def localProperties = new Properties()
def localPropertiesFile = rootProject.file('local.properties')
if (localPropertiesFile.exists()) {
    localPropertiesFile.withReader('UTF-8') { reader ->
        localProperties.load(reader)
    }
}

def flutterRoot = localProperties.getProperty('flutter.sdk')
if (flutterRoot == null) {
    throw new GradleException("Flutter SDK not found. Define location with flutter.sdk in the local.properties file.")
}

def flutterVersionCode = localProperties.getProperty('flutter.versionCode')
if (flutterVersionCode == null) {
    flutterVersionCode = '1'
}

def flutterVersionName = localProperties.getProperty('flutter.versionName')
if (flutterVersionName == null) {
    flutterVersionName = '1.0'
}

apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
apply plugin: 'kotlin-android'
apply from: "$flutterRoot/packages/flutter_tools/gradle/flutter.gradle"

android {
    compileSdkVersion flutter.compileSdkVersion
    ndkVersion flutter.ndkVersion
    
    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    }

    kotlinOptions {
        jvmTarget = '1.8'
    }

    sourceSets {
        main.java.srcDirs += 'src/main/kotlin'
    }

    defaultConfig {
        // TODO: Specify your own unique Application ID (https://developer.android.com/studio/build/application-id.html).
        applicationId "com.example.aiassistantapp"
        // You can update the following values to match your application needs.
        // For more information, see: https://docs.flutter.dev/deployment/android#reviewing-the-build-configuration.
        minSdkVersion 21
        targetSdkVersion flutter.targetSdkVersion
        versionCode flutterVersionCode.toInteger()
        versionName flutterVersionName
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            // TODO: Add your own signing config for the release build.
            // Signing with the debug keys for now, so `flutter run --release` works.
            signingConfig signingConfigs.debug
        }
    }
     aaptOptions {
        noCompress 'tflite'
        noCompress 'lite'
    }
}

flutter {
    source '../..'
}

dependencies {
    implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk7:$kotlin_version"
}
```

Can anyone help me please ? thank you

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70309075/problems-in-android-repository-flutter-tensorflow-lite-by-bintray-502

Answer (score 5):

So first, to get rid of this error you should
change this on
*~\tflite-1.1.2\android\build.gradle*:

```
dependencies {
    compile 'org.tensorflow:tensorflow-lite:+'
    compile 'org.tensorflow:tensorflow-lite-gpu:+'
}
```

to this:

```
dependencies {
    implementation 'org.tensorflow:tensorflow-lite:+'
    implementation 'org.tensorflow:tensorflow-lite-gpu:+'
}
```

Just change compile to implementation based on that [github issue in tflite](https://github.com/shaqian/flutter_tflite/issues/254#issuecomment-1145582629) to solve the issue that you post above.
for me it worked as a charm, but when I try to infer my models with some images, this error emerged
`Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Cannot convert between a TensorFlowLite tensor with type UINT8 and a Java object of type [[F (which is compatible with the TensorFlowLite type FLOAT32).`
and the whole application crash.
So if your model image based so check [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70965775/tensorflowlite-tensor-with-type-uint8-and-a-java-object-of-type-f-which-is-co) its related to quantization of model when you export yours.
Just do this:

```
config = QuantizationConfig.for_float16()
model.export(export_dir='.', tflite_filename='model_fp16.tflite', quantization_config=config)
```

hope this works for you!